# Shaking steering wheel while turning, squealing. Power steering?

Tags: subaru, power-steering, legacy, outback

My steering wheel is shaking when I turn.  It seems like the power steering is kicking in sporadically.  I only notice it when I'm going slow, and turning sharp (e.g. backing out of my driveway each morning).  I haven't noticed it while going fast, but I think it has more to do with the turning sharp part of it.

There's also a squealing sound that happens every time I start the car, and on and off while I'm driving it.  I can't seem to relate it to anything I'm doing, but it could be related to steering.

Yes, I already checked the power steering fluid.

The car is a '98 Subaru Legacy Outback.

Comment: Might be worth checking the belt condition and tension. Squealing is often the result of a belt slipping. I suppose that could also result in the kicking in (or out) that you're feeling. I think the system works harder at the extremes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was the accessory belt.  It was a small enough problem that I just ignored it until one day I heard a snap, and no longer had power steering (belt broke).  Replaced the belt, tightened it up, and it's been good ever since.